# Having lots of data, and how can I get it in a large list or are there other methods?

Tags: python

I am dealing with lots of data, about 100000 * 10kb. How can I get them into a list, what if my memory was less than 1gb?
This is my example. I'm not sure it would work.

```
def get_lots_of_data():
    datas = []
    for i in range(100000):
        d= find_a_big_data_from_file_by_item(i) #every item is about 10kb
        datas.append(d)
    return datas
```

How can I store this data properly?

Comment: what is your final goal?

Comment: if your memory is less than 1gb you're not going to be able to store 1gb of data in memory.

Comment: Maybe you should rethink if you really need all of the data in a list. Or maybe you're fine with storing a reference (counter or...) in that list.

Comment: @YuliaV I do know that "datas" is a huge object in memory. And I'm going to store it or return it in an proper way.

Answer (score 1):

you can return a generator rather than a list:

```
def get_lots_of_data():
    for i in range(100000):
        yield find_a_big_data_from_file_by_item(i)
```

The usage will be:

```
for d in get_lots_of_data():
    do_something(d)
```